# read a .vtp file without using VTK lib

Tags: c++, vtk

I have to build a very lightweight library in C++ and the core of this project is to read a superficial triangoular mesh from a .vtp file and then solve numerically some differential equation on it.

I have read how to do this using the VTK library (http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/ReadPolyData), but I'd rather write my own scripts.

Since the library will be loaded to R, I would like to keep it as lightweight as possibile and "self-contained", thus I'd rather not link to it the VTK library since it is needed just to import the triangoular mesh from the .vtp file.

Is there, to your knowledge, some ways of doing this?

Comment: [this might be what you need](http://www.vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf)

Comment: You can parse the .vtp file following the spec that Jacob H posted. However, it may be saved in binary format, in which case it won't be that easy. I suggest creating a standalone binary in c++ which would preprocess/convert your data from .vtp into a plain simple text format that is easy to use in R. This executable would link statically to vtk, to use the vtkPolydataReader, but would never change as long as you keep your format stable.